# @Scope("prototype") bean scope not creating new bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to use a annotated prototype bean in my controller. But spring is creating a singleton bean instead. Here is the code for that:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class LoginAction {

  private int counter;

  public LoginAction(){
    System.out.println(" counter is:" + counter);
  }
  public String getStr() {
    return " counter is:"+(++counter);
  }
}
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginAction loginAction;

    @RequestMapping(value="/view", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display(HttpServletRequest req){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
        mav.addObject("loginAction", loginAction);
        return mav;
    }

    public void setLoginAction(LoginAction loginAction) {
        this.loginAction = loginAction;
    }

    public LoginAction getLoginAction() {
        return loginAction;
    }
    }
```

Velocity template:

```
 LoginAction counter: ${loginAction.str}
```

Spring `config.xml` has component scanning enabled:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springheat" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I'm getting an incremented count each time. Can't figure out where am I going wrong!

**Update**

As [suggested by @gkamal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621968/254477), I made `HomeController` `webApplicationContext`-aware and it solved the problem.

updated code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value="/view", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display(HttpServletRequest req){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
        mav.addObject("loginAction", getLoginAction());
        return mav;
    }

    public LoginAction getLoginAction() {
        return (LoginAction) context.getBean("loginAction");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could double upvote you for implementing the correct answer in your code for others to see the actual difference

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Scope prototype means that every time you ask spring (getBean or dependency injection) for an instance it will create a new instance and give a reference to that.

In your example a new instance of LoginAction is created and injected into your HomeController . If you have another controller into which you inject LoginAction you will get a different instance.

If you want a different instance for each call - then you need to call getBean each time - injecting into a singleton bean will not achieve that.

Comment: I made the controller ApplicationContextAware and did getBean and I'm getting the fresh bean every time. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: How does this work if the bean would have had `request` scope instead of `prototype` scope. Would you still need to retrieve the bean with `context.getBean(..)`?

Comment: Or use a scoped proxy, i.e. @Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

Answer (score 43):

Since Spring **2.5** there's a very easy (and elegant) way to achieve that.

You can just change the params `proxyMode` and `value` of the `@Scope` annotation.

With this trick you can avoid to write extra code or to inject the ApplicationContext every time that you need a prototype inside a singleton bean.

Example:

```
@Service 
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  
public class LoginAction {}
```

With the config above `LoginAction` (inside `HomeController`) is always a *prototype* even though the controller is a *singleton*.

Comment: So we dont have it now in spring 5 ?

Answer (score 19):

Just because the bean injected into the controller is prototype-scoped doesn't mean the controller is!

Answer (score 12):

@controller is a singleton object, and if  inject a prototype bean to a singleton class will make the prototype bean also as singleton unless u specify using lookup-method property which actually create a new instance of prototype bean for every call you make.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by [nicholas.hauschild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343568/nicholas-hauschild) injecting Spring context is not a good idea. In your case, @Scope("request") is enough to fix it. But let say you need several instances of `LoginAction` in controller method. In this case, I would recommend to create the bean of Supplier ([Spring 4](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-generics-as-qualifiers) solution):

```
    @Bean
    public Supplier<LoginAction> loginActionSupplier(LoginAction loginAction){
        return () -> loginAction;
    }
```

Then inject it into controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private  Supplier<LoginAction> loginActionSupplier;
```

Comment: I would suggest injecting springs `ObjectFactory` which serves the same purpose as supplier, but can be defined as a normal `@Bean` by which I mean no need to return a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ApplicationContextAware` is tying you to Spring (which may or may not be an issue).  I would recommend passing in a `LoginActionFactory`, which you can ask for a new instance of a `LoginAction` each time you need one.

Comment: There's already Spring-specific annotations, though; doesn't seem like that's much of a concern.

Comment: @Dave, Good point.  There are alternatives for some of the DI stuff (JSR 311), but it may be harder to rid yourself of everything Spring dependent in this example.  I suppose I am really just advocating the `factory-method` here...

Comment: +1 for injecting a singleton `LoginActionFactory` into the Controller, but `factory-method` doesn't seem like it would solve the issue as it just creates another spring bean via the factory. Injecting that bean into the singleton Controller won't address the problem.

Comment: Good point Brad, I will remove that suggestion from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

use request scope `@Scope("request")` to get bean for each request, or `@Scope("session")` to get bean for each session 'user'

Answer (score 2):

A protoype bean injected inside a singelton bean will behave like singelton untill expilictly called for creating a new instance by get bean.

```
context.getBean("Your Bean")
```

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Spring beans are singletons. The problem arises when we
>   try to wire beans of different scopes. For example, a prototype bean
>   into a singleton. This is known as the scoped bean injection problem.

Another way to solve the problem is method injection with the [@Lookup](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lookup) annotation.

Here is a nice article on this issue of *injecting prototype beans into a singleton instance* with multiple solutions.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton

Answer (score 0):

class with `@Configuration`

```java
@Bean
@RequestScope //composed annotation for @Scope(value=...proxyMode=...)
public LoginAction requestScopedBean() {
    return new LoginAction ();
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Resource(name = "requestScopedBean")
    private LoginAction loginAction;

    //...your code here
```

Answer (score -1):

**@Component**

**@Scope(value="prototype")**

public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

// some code

}

Answer (score -12):

Your controller also need the `@Scope("prototype")` defined

like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class HomeController { 
 .....
 .....
 .....

}
```

Comment: why do u think controller also needs to be prototype?