# How to inject a prototype bean in a Spring singleton Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a FactoryBean for prototype beans like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationConfigurationMergedPropertiesFactoryBean implements SmartFactoryBean<Properties>{

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationConfigurationInitializer initializer;

    @Override
    public Properties getObject() throws Exception {
        return XXXXXXXXXX;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Properties.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPrototype() {
        return true;
    }
```

I would like to autowire it in a Controller and, whenever I try to access a property (via `p.get()`, have a new prototype instance from `ApplicationConfigurationMergedPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject()`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("applicationConfig")
  private Properties p;

  @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
  public String home() {
        System.out.println(p.get("something"));
  }
```

However this never calls getObject(). If I inject the ApplicationContext an access the bean directly, it works, providing a brand new Properties bean:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicationConfig")
    private Properties p;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String home() {
        System.out.println(p.get("something"));  //WRONG!!!!
        System.out.println(ac.getBean("applicationConfig", Properties.class).getProperty("something")); //OK!!!!
```

How can I achieve that directly with the @Autowired injection?

Comment: can't you just inject ApplicationConfigurationMergedPropertiesFactoryBean ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered making your controller class prototype-scoped as well?

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
```

Comment: I'd rather it were a singleton, I don't really need a new instance of the controller for every request...

Comment: Got ya, yeah this is the only way I know that you can accomplish what you want without explicitly calling your factory for every request. I used to feel the same way about not needing to create the controller for every request, but you might want to think about if it is really all that bad if it achieves the behavior you want and lets Spring handle the things that you don't want to explicitly. You may find that if you measure the performance of creating the controller each time that it adds negligible overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the factory directly:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicationConfig")
    private SmartFactoryBean p;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String home() {
        System.out.println(p.getObject()); 
   ....
   }
```

Comment: Yep, that is a solution. I was wondering if there was somethin less manual than invoking the factory directly. Like when you have a @Scoped("session" or "request") bean, which is automatically refreshed in the controller for every request