# How to get new bean per request in spring

Tags: java, spring-4

In the example below I want `person1` and `person2` to be different instances. How do I achieve that?

```
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private Person person;

    public void myMethod() {
        Person person1 = person; // new Person();
        Person person2 = person; // new Person();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the scope of the Person bean to 'prototype' either with xml:

```
<bean class="package.Person" scope="prototype"></bean>
```

Or annotation:

```
@Scope("prototype")
Person
```

Comment: Isn't `person` injected only once per new `Test` object? Two prototype-scoped `Person` members would give you two different `Person` objects, but wouldn't using the same one twice still give you only one? If you used `getBean` or used a factory member, then you'd achieve the desired results.

Comment: See in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7621920/3195526