# Clear/Initialize List(Collection) for every HTTP request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, list, collections

I'm working on Java for more than 4 years but new to Spring. I'm facing issue for initializing blank `List` for every single `PUT` request.

[image]

- `public abstract class BaseX implements InterfaceX`
- `public class DefaultX extends BaseX`
- `public class DefaultXAndY extends DefaultX`

**Issue:**

`List` used in class `BaseX` is not clearing for every HTTP `PUT` request. The code is as followed.

**InterfaceX.java**

```
public interface InterfaceX {
    public void process(Long id);
    public void publish();
}
```

**BaseX.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public abstract class BaseX implements InterfaceX{
    private List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public void addToList(Long id){
        System.out.println("Here in BaseX");
        listLong.add(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void publish() {
        System.out.println("Print list values");
        listLong.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**DefaultX.java**

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Resource(name = "defaultX")
public class DefaultX extends BaseX{

    @Override
    public void process(Long id) {
        //business logic
        System.out.println("Here in DefaultX");
        addToList(id);
    }
}
```

**DefaultXAndY.java**

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Resource(name = "defaultXAndY")
public class DefaultXAndY extends DefaultX{
    @Override
    public void process(Long id) {
        //Business logic different than X
        System.out.println("Here in DefaultXAndY");
        id = id + 10;
        super.process(id);
    }
}
```

**TestService.java**

```
public interface TestService {
    public void testServiceMethod(Long id);
}
```

**TestServiceImpl**

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.orderhive.inventory.service.TestService;
import com.orderhive.inventory.stock.InterfaceX;

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name = "defaultXAndY")
    private InterfaceX interfaceX; 

    @Override
    public void testServiceMethod(Long id) {
        interfaceX.process(id);
        interfaceX.publish();
        System.out.println("API call finished for id: " + id);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
}
```

**TestRestController**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.orderhive.inventory.service.TestService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService; 

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/number/{id}")
    void stockUpdate(@PathVariable Long id){
        testService.testServiceMethod(id);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
**PUT: localhost:8080/test/number/1**

Here in DefaultXAndY
Here in DefaultX
Here in BaseX
Print list values
11
API call finished for id: 1
--------------------------------
**PUT: localhost:8080/test/number/2**

Here in DefaultXAndY
Here in DefaultX
Here in BaseX
Print list values
11
12
API call finished for id: 2
--------------------------------
```

`List` is holding value from previous request.

===========================================================

**UPDATE**

Following changes worked for me but is it the best practice?

- removed `@Component` from `BaseX`
- `@Scope("request")` added in `DefaultX` and `DefaultXAndY`
- `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` added in `TestServiceImpl` suggested by @anatoly-shamov

===========================================================

**Solution:**

- removed `@Component` from `BaseX`
- `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` added in `DefaultX` and `DefaultXAndY`

Comment: have u ever used the notation @Bean. Use @Bean with the scope 'request` or `prototype`. because default scopes of  the bean is Singlton.

Comment: Since `Basex` is a Spring component(Bean) global variables will hold the previous values. It won't destroy from spring container since it is singleton

Comment: take a look at >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Scope("prototype") bean scope not creating new bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean)

Comment: I just opened up https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html . Here in `2.2.1` they used `AppConfig`. I want to do something like that then where should I put `AppConfig.java` and do I've to set it in `@ComponentScan` in my spring boot main application?

Comment: You shouldn't hold state in a singleton. Reconsider your design...

Comment: To all, Can you please check the **UPDATE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseX` is a bean of [singleton scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) (by default). It means there is only one instance of `BaseX` in Spring IoC container. All requests and references for that bean returns the same object.
You should abstract the `listLong` state with a separate bean of [request scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request). A new instance of this bean will be created for every HTTP request.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ListX {
    private List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public List<Long> getListLong() {
        return listLong;
    }

    public void setListLong(List<Long> listLong) {
        this.listLong = listLong;
    }
}
```

Use it in as `listLong` value holder in other components:

```
@Component
public abstract class BaseX implements InterfaceX{

    @Autowired
    ListX listHolder;

    public void addToList(Long id){
        System.out.println("Here in BaseX");
        listHolder.getListLong().add(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void publish() {
        System.out.println("Print list values");
        listHolder.getListLong().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll surely try this but considering your answer I've to do same for other variables in class `DefaultX` and `DefaultXAndY`. Can we get new instance of `DefaultXAndY` for every single request?

Comment: Sure you can. Just put a @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) annotation on the DefaultXAndY class.

Comment: Can you please check the **UPDATE**

Comment: Checked. As I understand, you need a new list for every request. So, as TestServiceImpl doesn't hold the list by itself - you don't need a @Scope(value = "request") on it. Just put this annotation on beans, which holds the list - DefaultX and DefaultXAndY.

Comment: `@Scope(value = "request")` doesn't work adding  `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` annotation to `DefaultX` and `DefaultXAndY` worked for me. Thanks for the help.