# how to create request type scope through annonation in spring mvc?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

requirement is that i want request type scope in particular bean Omsdashboard.java .i have to submit the architecture of controller where i want every time request i want new object .so this can be achieve by request scope because controller is by default singleton that why i cant not handle this problem please explain it. thanks for giving your time.
beans class
Omsdashborad.java

```
@Component
public class OMSDashBoard implements Serializable{
```

controller class

I am using autowire but they give singleton object but i want another object when project is loaded both method call onload time first call below method then call first method.

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
private OMSDashBoard omsDashBoard;

 public OMSDashBoard getOMSDashBoard() {
     System.out.println("@@2"+(OMSDashBoard) context.getBean("omsDashBoard"));
        return (OMSDashBoard) context.getBean("omsDashBoard");
    }
 @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setOmsDashBoard(@Qualifier("omsDashBoard") OMSDashBoard omsDashBoard) {
        this.omsDashBoard = omsDashBoard;

@RequestMapping(value = "/stuck/order/{fromDate}/{toDate}/{requestType}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<OMSDashBoard> getAllStcukOrdersByRequestType(@PathVariable("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @PathVariable("toDate") String toDate, @PathVariable("requestType") String orderTypeCd) {
    return new ResponseEntity<OMSDashBoard>(omsDashBoard, HttpStatus.OK);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "order/summary/{fromDate}/{toDate}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<OMSDashBoard> getOrderSummaryDetails(@PathVariable("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @PathVariable("toDate") String toDate) {
    return new ResponseEntity<OMSDashBoard>(omsDashBoard, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: What about prototype scope `@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class OMSDashBoard implements Serializable{}` ?

Comment: i will try this concept but its not working output i am getting singleton.we achieve only request type@AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: See the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621968/4423636 and let me know the status.

Comment: i am getting same hashcode when i use scope("prototype") like-1091291254 hashcode three time i am getting this id at the time of page load.

Comment: Did you follow the linked ?

Comment: i use @Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  line of code then so i getting error during compilation time  Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: Remove  `implements Serializable` from `OMSDashBoard`.

Comment: no effect same sout i am getting in hashcode of omsdashboard--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1409183393
------------------------1409183393@AtaurRahmanMunna so please help me this issue

Comment: Did you call `WebApplicationContext.getBean()`, not using autowire ?

Comment: i am getting errors--Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/eOMS] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException on fetch any data through omsdashborad object@AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna any idea about this issues i am try in myhand

Comment: Problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: if you want to code then i froward you mail through code@AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: You can found mail from my profile.

Comment: please check it  mail sir @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: please check it mail sir i will send the whole project.@AtaurRahmanMunna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step :
use scope(value="request") in omsdashboard.java
step-2
autowired
public AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context;
step-3
OMSDashBoard omsDashBoard = (OMSDashBoard) context.getBean(OMSDashBoard.class); in both method to get new object through bean.