# @Service and @Scope("prototype") together

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a service class with @Service and @Scope("protoype"). I want this service to behave like prototype in the controller class. Here is how I use it:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class LoginController {
  @Autowired
  private EmailService emailService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String register(){
    System.out.println(emailService);
    emailService.sendConfirmationKey();
  }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/resetKey", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    System.out.println(emailService);
    emailService.sendResetKey();
}
```

Here is the service class:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendConfirmationKey(){
    ...
    }
    public void sendResetKey(){
    ...
    }
}
```

I run spring boot using autoconfiguration property. I compare whether 'emailService' object is the same or not, and I get the same 
 one object. It means that @Scope("prototype") does not work as expected with @Service. Do you see anything wrong here? Did I forget a few more codes to add?

Edit:
Replying to @Janar, I do not want to use additional codes to make it work such as WebApplicationContext property and extra method to create. I know that there is a shorter way using only annotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Scope("prototype") bean scope not creating new bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean)

Comment: I have seen this post already, and yes, you might be right but I do not want to use context.getBean("beanName") and WebApplicationContext in the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must specify the proxy mode in the `scope` annotation.

This should do the trick:

```
@Service 
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  
public class EmailService {}
```

Alternatively you can define the `LoginController` as prototype as well.

Comment: I thought I tried that solution too but it did not work. I tried it now and it works. Thank you.
Do you know it is deprecated? I am using the latest versions of spring.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this will create new bean on each method call of the autowired proxy.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ScopedProxyMode.html this is the last stable version (5.0.4.RELEASE) and it's not deprecated