# Spring Autowired instance is always same on every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am using Spring Bean to create an instance and autowired the class and the same autowired fields object is returning from different classes by setting fields in the data.

For the first time, the data is properly coming, but on the second REST call, the same object is reflecting every time. I have tried to use Scope("prototype"), but it helps only for the first time. How can I get the proper data on every request?

```
@Service
@Scope(value="singleton",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MessageStats {
    private int count;
    //Setter & Getter
}

@Component
public class Main1 {

    @Autowired
    MessageStats messageStats;

    public MessageStats getStats() {

        // At runtime the data is populated for example: the first time as 10 and second time as 11
        messageStats.setCount(10);
    }

}

@Component
public class Main2 {

    @Autowired
    MessageStats messageStats;

    public MessageStats getStats() {

        // At runtime the data is populated for example: first time as 12 and second time as 13
        messageStats.setCount(12);
    }

 }
```

Output:

```
First time
10
12

Second time
10 expected is 11
12 expected is 13
```

The problem here is on my second API request the messageStats value is persisted and I need the value to get refreshed on every request to zero and I will repopulate the data.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575345/service-and-scopeprototype-together) might help you.

Comment: can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a singleton bean (i.e. `Main1` and `Main2`) has a prototype bean as its dependencies, the prototype bean is only created and injected into the singleton bean once when creating singleton bean. It will not create another new prototype bean when the singleton bean access the prototype bean later. This behavior is well explained at [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction).

If you want to create a new prototype instance whenever the singleton bean accesses the prototype bean, there are many [options](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton).

For example, I would use:

```java
public class Main1{

     @Autowired
     Provider<MessageStats> messageStats;

     public MessageStats getStats(){
        messageStats.get().setCount(10);
     }
 }
```

Comment: After changed to Scope("singleton") the first request is giving the prooper value but the second request also returns the same value.In runtime I am getting different values where If I create a instance MessageStats m=new MessageStats () only it is providing the value otherwise I am not getting second time different value.

Comment: actaully what is the behavouir you want?if you want a new messageState instance is created whenever you call Main.setCount(),use my solution. i never suggest you to use singleton for this behavouir

Comment: What is the Provider class here.I didn't understand the Provider.Can you please provide the example for Provider class.

Comment: It is the  class from JSR 330 which is `javax.inject.Provider`

Comment: I tried using Provider but the old value is persist where if there are more than 1 main classes with count1 and count2 fields the first value set by main1 is reflecting for main2 class.

Comment: no ideas what you actually as you still don't have answer my question about this (i.e. you want a new messageState instance is created whenever you call `Main.setCount()` ?) Also , I noticed that you edit your question which change the `MessageStats` 's Scope from prototype to singleton  , but my answer here is based on this change before. So , it makes the whole thing looks very confusing which my answer does not match with your question as you edit your question after my answer....

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `@Scope("prototype")` use `@Scope("singleton")`
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Answer (score 1):

Prototype creates a new object on every request, so it doesn't save state.