# Java Spring multiple nodes of a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl

I am new to Spring and my question is rather simple, I think, however, I cannot find any good resource. I have looked at beginner examples (like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm), [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/), and a few more) and have searched StackOverflow for answers, but I am not quite sure what I am supposed to search for.

Let me explain the scenario. Let's say I have a central node (C) and multiple internal nodes (I_1, ..., I_n), and this case:

```
I_1  
.
.    ------------------> C
.
I_n
```

In this very simple drawing I am trying to illustrate that each I_i sends something to C, when C asks for it. That's it. Now I want each I_i to have a special id, and they are sending that id to C.  How should I model this in Spring? As of now I have the basic setup

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I have a Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/i1/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String i1(
        @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

So if I run this code and curl to http://localhost:port/i1/560 it will return 560. I can create multiple nodes of this, of course, for example by creating a jar file and running it on different ports. The problem is that I can't really give them unique ID's. I mean, they are all an Application instance. I would like them to be of the node class below (or something similar):

```
class node{
    private int id;

    public node(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

So that I will have n internal nodes. And then I can open up a terminal and curl each of them to get their id. I hope I have explained reasonably well. In short: My aim is to have n instances of the node class, with unique id. And I want to curl them individually and get their id's, for example "curl http://localhost:8081/i1" will return i1's id, while "curl http://localhost:8082/i2" will return i2's id and so on. I'm not even sure what keywords I should use when searching. I have tried "spring multiple clients/hosts/applications" but not really found the right thing, so I would even appreciate an answer that contains just that.

**Beans**

I have read [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm), which does not really use a controller, but uses beans. I have tried this approach, which is sort of what I want to do, it can create multiple node objects, all with a unique id. However, I'm not sure if I can get each of them on to different nodes and ports.

Comment: So you want to have one executable that runs with different configurations (ports)?

Comment: @jAC Yes, I guess so. To clarify, right now I have the Application and Controller parts. I create a JAR file of that code. Then I run it multiple times with different ports by using java -Dserver.port=<port> -jar <file>. And that is the way I want to have it, if possible. This way I get several nodes on different ports.

Comment: OK, and every node should listen on a seperate port or should it all run within a single instance?

Comment: @jAC every node should listen on separate ports. If I run the jar file four times, as I wrote above, on ports 8080, ..., 8083, I will have created 4 nodes. I want these to be I_1, ..., I_4. So when I curl http://(...)/I1, I1 will answer with his id and so on. So I can gather all of their ids by curl:ing them.

Comment: Any restrictions on the node ID?

Comment: @Jan Larsen not really. ID was just an example. It can be anything, probably even anything from the ASCII table. It has to be sent from I_i to C, but I can just convert it to some format that is easy to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think your basic requirement is quite easy to achieve. 
But still there are questions regarding the index of your nodes `I_x`. Why do they even matter? 
If you have a port and an ID of your node, that sufficient to identify the node. So I created an answer with the following two properties:

- port
- ID

Following the restrictions mentioned above, you cannot create a `Controller` that listens on a specific mapping `I_x`. But that is not really needed as I see.

Create a class `NodeInformation` that holds the values:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class NodeInformation {
    private int port;
    private int id;


    public NodeInformation(int port, int id) {
        this.port = port;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

`@Getter` and `@Setter` are `org.projectlombok` annotations that automatically create setter and getter.

Then fill the needed information by parsing your configuration.
This config can be either set by:

- application.properties
- passing arguments (`-Dnode.port=xy` `-Dnode.id=myid`)

ATTENTION: Alternatively you can use the spring stock property `server.port` that automatically sets the port.

So filling the info in you `NodeInformation`, you have to use a `@Configuration` `NodeInformationConfiguration`, that builds and returns your `Bean`:

```
@Configuration
public class NodeInformationConfiguration {

    private final int port;
    private final int id;

    public NodeInformationConfiguration(@Value("${node.port}") int port, @Value("${node.id}") int id) {
        this.port = port;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Bean
    public NodeInformation getNodeInfo() {
        return new NodeInformation(port, id);
    }
}
```

So in the end you have to set your port and create a Controller that returns your id.

**Setting the port**

You can set your port by using the `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`. Use the NodeInformation we previously created by Autowiring it to your class `PortSetter`.

```
@Component
public class PortSetter {


    private final int port;

    @Autowired
    public PortConfiguration(NodeInformation nodeInformation) {
        this.port = nodeInformation.getPort();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setPort(port);
        });
    }
}
```

And finally create a simple RestController that returns your set Id by listening on `/id`:

```
@RestController
public class NodeController {

    private final NodeInformation nodeInformation;

    @Autowired
    public NodeController(NodeInformation nodeInformation) {
        this.nodeInformation = nodeInformation;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/id")
    public int getNodeId() {
        return this.nodeInformation.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup with one node and one controller in one application with one port is simple, but will likely cause memory problems along the way. You probably want one application that runs node-threads that each take a port.

Taking your question at face value, he simplest would be to make nodes Components using `@Scope` "prototype" (so they are not singletons if you add another later) then `@Autowire` one to your controller, then use `UUID` for id so it is always unique and just set it when creating the node:

```
private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

with a getter. Then the controller can get the id from its own node.

Comment: Do you mean sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean)? How do I make sure they run on different ports?