# Prototype bean inside @Controller not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scope, captcha

I have a controller that contains two methods. First one generates a random captcha value, and second one compares that and the input the user wrote. The problem was when multiple users tried to validate the captcha value, the last generated value was validated correctly to preview generated values for other users.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class CaptchaController {

    private Producer captchaProducer = null;

    @Autowired
    private DataCaptcha dataCaptcha;

    @Autowired
    public void setCaptchaProducer(Producer captchaProducer) {
        this.captchaProducer = captchaProducer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/generate-captcha.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String captchaText = captchaProducer.createText();

        dataCaptcha.setCaptcha(captchaText);
        dataCaptcha.setPasoCaptcha(false);

        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ "+ dataCaptcha.getCaptcha()); // output: null

        BufferedImage bi = captchaProducer.createImage(captchaText);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate-captcha.json", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> validarCaptcha(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(value = "valueCaptcha", defaultValue = "") String valueCaptcha) {

        String captchaId = dataCaptcha.getCaptcha();
        Boolean rpta = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(captchaId, valueCaptcha);
        String message = "";
        String messageType = "OK";
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        if (!rpta) {
            message = "incorrect captcha";
            messageType = "ERROR";
            dataCaptcha.setPasoCaptcha(false);
        } else {
            dataCaptcha.setPasoCaptcha(true);
        }
        response.put("messageType", messageType);
        response.put("message", message);
        response.put("object", rpta);
        return response;
    }
}
```

That error was due to @Controller bean singleton and I needed a Prototype scope in my bean. So I tried different ways to do this:

- Making the controller webApplicationContext-aware, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean)
- Using @Lookup, example [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/using-lookup-method.html)
- Finally tried Scope Proxy as described [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/scoped-proxy.html)

**DataCaptcha**:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataCaptcha {
    private String captcha;
    private boolean pasoCaptcha;
}
```

Non of them worked. Tried debugging and in this particular line on the controller

```
String captchaText = captchaProducer.createText();
dataCaptcha.setCaptcha(captchaText);
```

**captchaText** has a value, but after using **setCaptcha** and checking the object **dataCaptcha**, the **captcha** field is null.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.3

Comment: `dataCaptcha` probably needs to be a session scoped bean - [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your DataCaptcha variable should not be a class variable as your have it in the controller, but instead be a variable inside your handleRequest method.

Then, using the spring context (as you hinted at), perform a

```
DataCaptcha dataCaptcha = ctx.getBean(DataCaptcha.class)
```

to get a prototyped instance.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton Bean holds the reference to same prototype bean throughout its lifetime. You are right, you need to have the DataCaptcha in prototype scope or else it would be shared between threadContexts and multiple users would be able to use the same captcha. But also, You need to have it inside method and cannot have it at class level, because if its class level, there would be just one object created of controller class (singleton bean) and its associated DataCaptcha would be same.

As you already pointed, webApplicationContext-aware, you need to get a new local instance of DataCaptcha inside your methods. You can try to have a unique ID added to DataCaptcha and retrieve the captcha using the ID for validation purpose. Or you may put it in userSession object on server side, and clear it off once it is validated successfully.