# what is default scope of an jpa entity bean? how it is helpful?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

All the entity bean in my project looks something like this, I wanted to know what is significance of using @scope("prototype") for entity.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Entity
@Table(name = SOME_BEAN.SOME_CONSTANT)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Scope("prototype") bean scope not creating new bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621920/scopeprototype-bean-scope-not-creating-new-bean)

Comment: Scoping a JPA entity isnt' useful. It isn't spring managed so making it a component etc. is hardly ever useful.

Answer (score 1):

Default scope of an entity is Singleton - Here only one instance of your bean will be created and that will be returned in every subsequent request call.

In case of Prototype scope, new bean instance will be created for each request to that bean.