# How does @Entity annotated bean handle multiple request?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-annotations

I have investigated it before post but could not find answer.
I found similar answer but not exactly I want to know.
@Entity annotation creates singleton object, but entity has state.
How spring boot handle multiple request in this situation? If there are 10 requests it means
there are should be one object with 10 different state. How it possible?
Could you please explain me this question in @Entity perspective ?

Thanks you!

I want to know, how spring/hibernate handle multiple request with @Entity annotation.

Comment: @Entity is Entity :)! An Entity is mapped to a database table, an Entity instance should be seen as a table row. Spring does not manage entities

Answer (score 0):

The class annotated with [@Entity](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entity) annotation is mapped to a table with matching class name or name mentioned in annotation

```
@Entity
public class Customer // mapped to customer table

@Entity(name="cust")
public class Customer // mapped to cust table
```

In spring boot the class annotated with `@Entity` will be scanned and will be mapped to table in database. Spring will never create singleton object for class annotated with Entity.

The table rows are mapped into entity object's and each record will be mapped into each entity object, so if there are 10 row then 10 entity objects will be created.

Comment: Thank you for your response.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374642/what-is-default-scope-of-an-jpa-entity-bean-how-it-is-helpful discussion in this topic just confused me. I agree that spring ioc does not manage entity. It is managed by hibernate itself. Can we define scope for Entity? What is default scope? I understood that it is prototype or just simple class.